# CUDA C++ copy object pointers to device

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

```
class bead {
int ID;
__host__ __device__ bead(int id){ID=id};
}
void main(void){
vector<bead*> beadvec;
for(int i=0;i<128;i++){
bead* b1=new bead(i);
beadvec.pushback(b1);
}
}
```

Am not sure how to copy the vector of pointers (beadvec) to the device.
Should I rely on cudaMemCpy and cudaMalloc functions or if there is a thrust function to do it effectively*/
In the device code, I want to access each bead and do elementary operations on ID.

Comment: The concepts necessary here are covered in many other questions here on the CUDA SO tag, and are even mentioned in the [tag info link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) "Using arrays of pointers in CUDA.".  You may be making things quite a bit more difficult than they need to be by coming up with a storage formulation that is an array of pointers.  An array of objects of this type (rather than an array of pointers to objects) would be trivial by comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I went through those questions before posting this one. I was of the opinion that copying vector of object pointers will consume lesser time than merely copying a vector of object to the device. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your vector of object pointers, where each object is individually allocated with `new`, can't be copied to the device conveniently at all, and will require a loop to copy, amongst other issues. the question I pointed out is  a question discussing how to handle an array of pointers.  Do you suppose that it has no bearing on your question, which is essentially how to handle an array of pointers?

Comment: The question I linked, plus many others, suggest flattening such allocations, for ease of use, ease of copying to the device, and efficient access on the device.  Converting from a vector of pointers to a vector of objects is a form of flattening in this case.

Answer (score 1):

'cuMemcpyHtoD' can be used to copy object pointers to device.

I copy pointers to device in JCuda like this:

```
private void updateArrayPointer(CUdeviceptr arrayPointer, CUdeviceptr[] elementPtrs) {
    JCudaDriver.cuMemcpyHtoD(arrayPointer, Pointer.to(elementPtrs), maxBatchSize * Sizeof.POINTER);
}
```

Here, 'arrayPointer' is like one 'float**' in cuda kernel. Many CUdeviceptr (like float*) are assigned to elementPtrs on CPU first, and call cuMemcpyHtoD like above to form one 'float**' on device. Sizeof.POINTER is 8 on a 64-bit system.